# No window display using OpenGL with Python3.4

Tags: python, opengl

I was trying to write Snake Game for practice with:
http://noobtuts.com/python/snake-game

Required:

```
Python - check
Python OpenGL - check
```

I used few ready codes that should **display a window** where game would be.

Example:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

window = 0                                             # glut window number
width, height = 500, 400                               # window size

def draw():                                            # ondraw is called all the time
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # clear the screen
    glLoadIdentity()                                   # reset position

    # TODO draw rectangle

    glutSwapBuffers()                                  # important for double buffering


# initialization
glutInit()                                             # initialize glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)                      # set window size
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)                           # set window position
window = glutCreateWindow(b"noobtuts.com")              # create window with title
glutDisplayFunc(draw)                                  # set draw function callback
glutIdleFunc(draw)                                     # draw all the time
glutMainLoop()                                         # start everything
```

All I get as a result is:

```
Process started >>>
```

**No window is displayed.**

I tried to update my graphics drivers but that didn't work.

To check if window is displayed I used:

```
print(window != 0)
```

Which returns True.